# Objective C Delegate in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, chartboost

I just implemented Chartboost into my all swift app.

I have rewarded interstitials.  So I need to set up a delegate using the objective C function Chartboost gave me.  I cannot figure out how to do it.  This is how I did Admob via Swift.

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "presentInterstitial:", name: "AdMobCall", object: nil) 

   func presentInterstitial(sender:UIButton!) {

    if let isReady = interstitial?.isReady {   // _ isReady
        interstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self)

    }
}

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("AdMobCall", object: nil)
```

But the Objective C Chartboost function I am given is:

- (void)didCompleteRewardedVideo:(CBLocation)location
                withReward:(int)reward;

And I do not understand how to create the same delegate I did for Admob using this function.  it doesn't seem possible.   I have the Chartboost rewarded intersitials working.  But I have no way of setting up the delegate to see if they watched the video to completion or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want achieve objective-c delegate in to swift. You need to do following steps.

1. Need to create bridge file to import your objective-c classes

   ```
   //
   //  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
   //

   #import "UVIViewController.h"
   ```
2. You need to extend the protocol name in your swift viewcontroller

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UVIViewController, UVIDataRefreshProtocol {   // 2. Extend Protocal

       var secondController: DelegateViewController?

       @IBOutlet var delegateRefresh: UILabel!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

           self.registerForBasicDataRefreshNotification();             //  3. Register the protocol notification
       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }

       // Register the protocol notification with same name. Example : DataRefreshNotification
       override func registerForBasicDataRefreshNotification() {

           self.validateBasicDataRefreshNotification();
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(        // 4. Register the protocol notification with same name.
               self,
               selector: "basicDataDidRefresh",
               name: DataRefreshNotification,
               object: nil)

       }

       override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
           delegateRefresh.text = "";
           if segue.identifier == "view_to_delegate" {
               secondController = segue.destinationViewController as? DelegateViewController
           }
       }

       // Basic Data Did Refresh Notification
       func basicDataDidRefresh() {                            //  4. Event will be triggered while calling the protocol post notification. called with same name
               NSLog("\n Basic data is refreshed")
               delegateRefresh.text = "Basic data is refreshed";
       }

   }
   ```

---

```
    5. NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DataRefreshNotification, object: nil)  // Call the notification.
```

Sample Project: https://github.com/vigneshuvi/Objective-C-Delegate-Swift